# JNI : Using method with custom return type

Tags: java, java-native-interface

It's my first time to use JNI.

I declare the methods using native keyword and then I use them successfully as required.

but I can't load a method which has custom return type.

like :

```
public native Feature[] getFeatures();
```

I added a class called feature but it seams that this method cannot be loaded. it gives me an exception.
when I debugged it.
in the ClassLoader class method

```
static long findNative(ClassLoader loader, String name) {
    Vector libs =
    loader != null ? loader.nativeLibraries : systemNativeLibraries;
synchronized (libs) {
    int size = libs.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        NativeLibrary lib = (NativeLibrary)libs.elementAt(i);
    long entry = lib.find(name);
    if (entry != 0)
        return entry;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

It cannot find my declared function . and fires NoSuchMethodError.

Is it because of the return type ? because when I declare methods which returns int or boolean it works fine.

This is what I have.

the C header contains:

```
/*
 * Class:     com_trial_JHeap
 * Method:    getFeatures
 * Signature: ()[Lcom/trial/JHeap/Feature;
 */
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_com_trial_JHeap_getFeatures
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);
/*
 * Class:     com_trial_JHeap
 * Method:    setMZException
 * Signature: (II)Z
 */
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_trial_JHeap_setMZException
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint, jint);
```

and my java class :

```
public class JHeap {
   static {
        System.loadLibrary("JHeap");       
}

public class  Feature {

  public Feature() {
  }
}

public JHeap() {
}

public native boolean setMZException(int check_interval,int retry_interval);
/**
 * 
 * @return
 */
public native JHeap.Feature[] getFeatures();
 }
}
```

I don;t have the c files. I only get the so lib

Comment: There's no problem using "custom" classes as either return types or as method arguments. In this case you have given us too little information on what the problem is. "it gives me an exception" is way to broad.

Comment: I've added some details. The problem is that I don't know why it cannot find it while I added a class called Feature to match its return type

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with that code? Load the library with the native code? Use `System.loadLibrary()` for that.

Comment: You need to post (1) the contains class, including its package , (2) the generated .h file and (3) the relevant part of the .c or .cpp file, specifically what it includes and what methods it defines.

Comment: added everything I have :)

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't have the c files. I only get the so lib"? You must do the implementation of the JNI library and use the generated `.h` file for it. So the `.c` file must be there somewhere...

Comment: If you are trying to use some non-jni library then I suggest that you use JNA instead of JNI. I don't think you have fully understood how to use JNI.

Comment: So you have a Java method `heapLost()` and a native method `…_getFeatures` and are asking why it doesn’t work?

Comment: I have the shared object that contains the implementation of the functions. I'm a user for the library not implementer

Comment: So did you retry it now that you gave the method the right name?

Comment: Ok so just follow what @Holger suggests. Your method names are wrong according to the JNI library.

Comment: @Holger : no it was just a mistake to copy.
but it is called that name in the file.
I've modified it.

Comment: The problem is that you’re saying that you have a fixed .so file so it doesn’t matter what’s in your header file as you don’t recompile the native code. So it’s pointless changing method names and signatures as the methods of your Java code declared `native` must exactly match the symbols contained in the .so file. You cannot change the methods without adapting the native code.

Comment: please ignore this error. this was due to copying from my code files to stackoverflow.
but what is written now is what is right for code an header file .

Comment: It might match the header file but as I said before, the header file doesn’t matter if you cannot compile the native library by yourself. The native method’s signatures are *fixed* in the .so file.